# HP procurve 5412zl ACL

Tags: switch, hp-procurve

I'm new to HP ProCurve and I am a problem getting host in a vlan connected to the internet.  I am not certain if the ACL is blocking internet traffic or if there is someother configuration issue.  I would like to temporarily disable the ACL without removing all of the rules.  Is there a command in this model to disble the ACL. I tried the "ip dont-use-acl" command and received and "Invalid input: dont-use-acl" error.

```
Core Switch config:<br/>
hostname "Prod-Core"<br/>
module 1 type j8702a<br/>
module 2 type j8702a<br/>
module 3 type j8702a<br/>
module 4 type j8702a<br/>
module 5 type j9309a<br/>
module 6 type j8702a<br/>
mirror 1 port A24<br/>
fault-finder broadcast-storm sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder bad-driver sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder bad-transceiver sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder bad-cable sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder too-long-cable sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder over-bandwidth sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder loss-of-link sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-hdx sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-fdx sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder link-flap sensitivity high<br/>
power-over-ethernet pre-std-detect ports F1-F24<br/>
timesync sntp<br/>
sntp unicast<br/>
sntp 60<br/>
sntp server priority 1 10.100.12.33<br/>
sntp server priority 2 10.100.12.32<br/>
time daylight-time-rule continental-us-and-canada<br/>
time timezone -360<br/>
web-management idle-timeout 900<br/>
ip access-list extended "vlan68-DEVEL_ACL"<br/>
     10 remark "ACL Applied to the vlan 68 interface (in)"<br/>
     11 remark "-----------------------------------------"<br/>
     12 remark "Allow traffic to flow within the DEVEL vlan"<br/>
     13 permit ip 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255<br/>
     22 remark "Allow 80, 443 for Exchange and KBOX"<br/>
     23 remark "-----------------------------------------"<br/>
     24 permit tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.15.40 0.0.0.0 eq 80<br/>
     25 permit tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.15.40 0.0.0.0 eq 443<br/>
     26 permit tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.15.91 0.0.0.0 eq 80<br/>
     27 permit tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.15.91 0.0.0.0 eq 443<br/>
     28 permit tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.15.98 0.0.0.0 eq 80<br/>
     29 permit tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.15.98 0.0.0.0 eq 443<br/>
     30 remark "Block 80, 443"<br/>
     31 remark "-----------------------------------------"<br/>
     32 deny tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.12.0 0.0.3.255 eq 80<br/>
     33 deny tcp 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.12.0 0.0.3.255 eq 443<br/>
     80 remark "Allow Other Dev to Prod traffic"<br/>
     81 remark "-------------------------------"<br/>
     82 permit ip 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 10.100.12.0 0.0.3.255<br/>
     90 remark "Allow Everything else (Internet)"<br/>
     91 remark "--------------------------------"<br/>
     92 permit ip 10.100.68.0 0.0.3.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255<br/>
     100 remark "Allow return Internet traffic"<br/>
     101 remark "--------------------------------"
     102 permit ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255<br/>
   exit<br/>
ip authorized-managers 10.100.12.0 255.255.252.0 access manager<br/>
ip default-gateway 10.100.12.1<br/>
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.100.12.1<br/>
ip routing<br/>
..........<br/>
..........<br/>
..........<br/>
snmp-server community "public" unrestricted<br/>
snmp-server host 10.100.13.130 community "public" trap-level critical<br/>
snmp-server contact "Dave Guyton - 2463" location "HQ"<br/>
vlan 1<br/>
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"<br/>
   no untagged D1-D3,D7,D9,D11,D14,D16,E1-E4,F1-F24<br/>
   untagged A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D4-D6,D8,D10,D12-D13,D15,D17-D24<br/>
   ip address 10.100.12.10 255.255.252.0<br/>
   ip local-proxy-arp<br/>
   forbid D14,D16<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 5<br/>
   name "CharterInternetHA"<br/>
   untagged D1-D3<br/>
   no ip address<br/>
   forbid A1-A24,B3-B24,C1-C24,D5-D24<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 6<br/>
   name "AT&TInternetHA"<br/>
   untagged D7,D9,D11<br/>
   no ip address<br/>
   forbid A1-A24,B3-B24,C1-C24,D1-D6,D8,D10,D12-D24<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 7<br/>
   name "iSCSI VLAN"<br/>
   untagged E1-E4,F1-F24<br/>
   no ip address<br/>
   forbid A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 10<br/>
   name "DMZ-Guest-WLAN"<br/>
   tagged D14,D16,D20<br/>
   no ip address<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 68<br/>
   name "DEVEL-68"<br/>
   tagged A19,D23-D24<br/>
   ip access-group "vlan68-DEVEL_ACL" in<br/>
   ip address 10.100.68.1 255.255.252.0<br/>
   ip local-proxy-arp<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 72<br/>
   name "VOICE"<br/>
   tagged D23-D24<br/>
   ip address 10.100.72.1 255.255.255.0<br/>
   ip local-proxy-arp<br/>
   dhcp-server<br/>
   exit<br/>
no spanning-tree bpdu-throttle<br/>
no autorun<br/>
no dhcp config-file-update<br/>
no dhcp image-file-update<br/>
dhcp-server pool "vlan72-Voice"<br/>
   authoritative<br/>
   default-router "10.100.72.1"<br/>
   dns-server "10.100.12.33,10.100.12.32"<br/>
   domain-name "memco.local"<br/>
   lease 08:00:00<br/>
   network 10.100.72.0 255.255.255.0<br/>
   option 4 ip "10.100.12.33,10.100.12.32"<br/>
   option 42 ip "10.100.12.33,10.100.12.32"<br/>
   option 156 ascii "ftpservers=10.100.13.16, layer2tagging=1, vlanid=72"<br/>
   range 10.100.72.75 10.100.72.253<br/>
   exit<br/>
dhcp-server enable<br/><br/>

 IP Route Entries<br/><br/>

  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.<br/>
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----<br/>
  0.0.0.0/0          10.100.12.1     1    static               1          1<br/>
  10.100.12.0/22     DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            1          0<br/>
  10.100.68.0/22     DEVEL-68        68   connected            1          0<br/>
  10.100.72.0/24     VOICE           72   connected            1          0<br/>
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0<br/>
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0<br/><br/><br/>
Dev Switch Config:<br/>
hostname "DEV-4th floor"<br/>
module 1 type j8702a<br/>
module 2 type j8702a<br/>
module 3 type j8702a<br/>
module 4 type j8702a<br/>
module 5 type j8702a<br/>
module 6 type j8702a<br/>
module 7 type j8702a<br/>
module 8 type j8702a<br/>
mirror 1 port A24<br/>
mirror 3 port A8<br/>
fault-finder broadcast-storm sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder bad-driver sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder bad-transceiver sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder bad-cable sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder too-long-cable sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder over-bandwidth sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder loss-of-link sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-hdx sensitivity high<br/>
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-fdx sensitivity high<br/>
power-over-ethernet pre-std-detect ports B13,B23,C19,F20,F22,F24,H1-H24<br/>
qos device-priority 10.100.13.116/0 priority 7<br/>
timesync sntp<br/>
sntp unicast<br/>
sntp 60<br/>
sntp server priority 1 10.100.12.33<br/>
sntp server priority 2 10.100.12.32<br/>
time daylight-time-rule continental-us-and-canada<br/>
time timezone -360<br/>
ip authorized-managers 10.100.12.0 255.255.252.0 access manager<br/>
ip default-gateway 10.100.12.1<br/>
ip timep manual 10.100.12.32<br/>
..........<br/>
..........<br/>
..........<br/>
snmp-server community "public" unrestricted<br/>
snmp-server host 10.100.12.45 community "public" trap-level not-info<br/>
no snmp-server enable traps link-change A4<br/>
snmp-server contact "Dave Guyton - 2463" location "HQ"<br/>
vlan 1<br/>
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"<br/>
   no untagged G19,G21,G23,H1-H24<br/>
   untagged A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F24,G1-G18,G20,G22,G24<br/>
   ip address 10.100.12.9 255.255.252.0<br/>
   forbid G19,G21,G23<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 10<br/>
   name "GuestVLAN"<br/>
   tagged G19,G21,G23<br/>
   no ip address<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 68<br/>
   name "DEVEL-68"<br/>
   untagged H1-H24<br/>
   tagged B19<br/>
   ip address 10.100.68.9 255.255.252.0<br/>
   exit<br/>
vlan 72<br/>
   name "VOICE"<br/>
   tagged A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F19,F21,F23,G1-G6,G8-G24,H1-H24<br/>
   ip address 10.100.72.9 255.255.255.0<br/>
   forbid F20,F22,F24,G7<br/>
   exit<br/>
no spanning-tree bpdu-throttle<br/>
no autorun<br/>
no dhcp config-file-update<br/>
no dhcp image-file-update<br/><br/>

 IP Route Entries<br/><br/>

  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.<br/>
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----<br/>
  0.0.0.0/0          10.100.12.1     1    static               250        1<br/>
  10.100.12.0/22     DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            1          0<br/>
  10.100.68.0/22     DEVEL-68        68   connected            1          0<br/>
  10.100.72.0/24     VOICE           72   connected            1          0<br/>
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0<br/>
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0<br/>
```

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: configuration from the device would help. Typically, you would just remove the command applying the ACL to an interface. This won't remove the ACL, just it's use on the interface in question.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, this one is clear enough.. it's just "how to disable ACL in a Procurve 5400". As a starting point, the requester is apparently reading wrong manual. "ip dont-use-acl" was used with old 9000-series routers, but not current ProVision devices. Any command on those is negated with preceding "no" - so if ACL is assigned with command "assign acl to interface" it's disabled with "no assign acl to interface". Note that these commands are equally invalid, can't remember them offhand. However ACLs and their usage is pretty thoroughly explained in Access Security Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, config makes it easier :)

When you look at the config file, each item (excluding "module") is a configuration command you can give on the CLI. And every command is negated with a preceding "no". So if you want to disable the ACL for a duration, just

```
no ip access-group "vlan68-DEVEL_ACL" in
```

This will remove it from the interface, but won't touch the rules. When you're done with testing, give command

```
ip access-group "vlan68-DEVEL_ACL" in
```

and it's re-applied. Of course since this is applied to a VLAN, you need to be in the VLAN configuration context, so this is what it looks like in practice (with the prompt):

```
configure 
vlan 68
no ip access-group "vlan68-DEVEL_ACL" in
```

This will change the running config. If you need the configuration w/o ACL to survive a reboot, you need to give command

```
write memory
```

last to save to startup config. Even after this you re-apply the ACL the same way, just don't forget to "write memory" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the info Arimo. I was able to confirm that the acl was not the cause of my connection issue. I must be a routing issue somewhere on the network.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could remove the application of ACL from the interface first, edit or rewrite (copy-paste) your ACL and re-apply to the interface. This is if I got you right.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by adding a return route on the firewall to the 10.100.68.0 network. Not certain that this was the best solution. But, the vlan no has an Internet connection.

Comment: Well yes, not having a return route would cause problems :D Good to know you got it up'n running now. If the solution works, it's the best one :)